# Is there a solution possible for the following equation

Tags: roots, lambert-w

I have to find the solution of the following equation $$e^{\frac{a}{ax+1}}=(ax+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ where $a>0$. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my attempt:

taking $(ax+1)$ power on both sides we get $$e^{a}=(ax+1)^{a+\frac{1}{x}}$$ Now taking $x$ power on both sides we get $$e^{ax}=(ax+1)^{ax+1}$$ by using $ax+1=z$ we can write $$e^{z-1}=z^z$$ which I think is pretty much solve able but I am not sure.

Comment: Have you read the answers to your previous, almost identical question? Here the problem boils down to solving $\exp\frac{z}{z+1}=z+1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes I have read answer to the other question. I have added my attempt in this question. Can you point my mistake. I am unable to see the mistake please help me where I am wrong here?

Comment: There is no mistake, just a not efficient substitution. If you assume $x>0$ and raise both sides to the $x$ power you are left with $$\exp\frac{ax}{ax+1}=ax+1$$ which is clearly associated with the solutions of $$\exp\frac{z}{z+1}=z+1.$$ The dependency on $a$ is gone through the substitution $ax=z$.

Comment: Then by setting $z=\frac{u}{1-u}$ this boils down to $(1-u)e^u = 1$ which is solved only by $u=0$ by concavity/since the origin is the location of an absolute maximum.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you for your comment. Perhaps you wanted to say by $u=0$. How do you think solving of this problem becomes difficult if we multiply by constant (c) the right side of the equation?